# view holder holds wrong value

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I have a ListView and a SimpleCursorAdapter. I add two rows (each is a reminder): the first has a title, date and countdown string, the second has a title and an address (location).
For some reason, the ViewHolder's mCountDownString from row #2 has the value from row #1.
Doesn't it create a ViewHolder object for each row? If yes, why isn't mCountDownString empty for the address reminder row?

```
private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView mTitle;
    TextView mDate;
    String mDateString;
    TextView mCountDown = null;
    String mCountDownString;
    TextView mAddress;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    mCursor = (Cursor) getItem(position);

    if(convertView == null) 
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

        holder.mTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleID);

        //holder.mAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateTimeOrLocationID);
        //holder.mDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateTimeOrLocationID);
        // edit: changed to use a separate view 
        holder.mAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.addressId);
        holder.mDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateTimeId);
        holder.mCountDown = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.countdownID);
        holder.mCountDownString = null;
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
           holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

       int colorPos = mCursor.getPosition() % colors.length;
       convertView.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);

       int col = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ReminderColumns.TITLE);
       holder.mTitle.setText(mCursor.getString(col));

       col = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ReminderColumns.ADDRESS);
       String address = mCursor.getString(col);

       if(address != null)
       {
            // No. 1: it's an address: set only title + address fields
           System.out.println("title for address: " + holder.mTitle.getText());
           holder.mAddress.setText(address);
           holder.mDate.setText(""); // edit
           holder.mCountDown.setText("");
           holder.mCountDownString = "";
       }
       else
       {
           // No. 2: it's date: set only title + date + countDownString fields
           col = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ReminderColumns.DATE);
           Date date = new Date(mCursor.getLong(col));
           SimpleDateFormat timeFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm");
           String dateStr = timeFormat2.format(date);

           holder.mDate.setText(dateStr);
           String countDownStr = getTimeDiff(date);
           holder.mCountDown.setText(countDownStr);
           holder.mCountDownString = countDownStr;
           holder.mAddress.setText(""); // edit
       }
    return convertView;
}
```

**EDIT**
I clear all holder's member variables if they're not used. But the problem still persists: for a date row, it doesn't display holder.mDate and for a address row, it doesn't show holder.mAddress. Something is mixed up.
When I create the adapter, the cursor is initially null. That's why I'm setting it in getView().

**Edit 2**
I changed my code so I'm not using dateTimeOrLocationID for holder.mAddress and holder.mDate. The problem now is, that there's an empty view which takes up space. F.e. if I add a date and leave R.id.addressId empty, the empty space is still visible. Is there a way to avoid that? And would you mind explaning why my first approach didn't work?

```
<LinearLayout  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:focusable="false" 
    android:clickable="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/titleID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
         android:focusable="false" 
        android:clickable="false"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/dateTimeId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:focusable="false" 
        android:clickable="false" 
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/addressId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:focusable="false" 
        android:clickable="false" 
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/countdownID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:focusable="false" 
        android:clickable="false"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The first approach could work. You just gotta remember its only 1 view but you put in a different value depending on your data. First approach is best but you could make second work by setting view.setVisibility(View.GONE) or view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

Comment: I did change the value depending on if it's a Date or an Address. Would you mind pointing out in the code why the first approach didn't work? When I entered a new address: it should show the Title and the Address. But it also showed the Date (of the first row)

Comment: It's 1 view but you are setting the values of the same view twice. You should instead make an if(something) { do this } else { do that } then you only set the value once and you wont override the values in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't create a viewholder for each row in your list. You got 1 viewholder for each convertview which is about as many rows that can be shown at the screen simoultanously. You need to update the content each time getView is called.

**Edit**:

Your mDate and mAddress use the same view. Search for:  R.id.dateTimeOrLocationID abd it becommes clear to you :)

Comment: I edited my question and cleared some strings of the view holder. The problem still exists though. From what I understand after reading [this](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/) tutorial, it seems that each convertView is a row. Or did I misunderstand that?

Comment: @user2246120 each convertview is a scrapview which is being recycled. That means you need to overwrite the values every time getView is called. If you don't overwrite it, the old value will still show.

Comment: @user2246120 you should remove mCursor.moveToPosition(position) and just check the convertView first. Then if it has a holder you should update the content based on the content from your cursor at the position.

Comment: ok, I removed mCursor.moveToPosition(position) and clear all fields that don't matter (clear address when the date is set & clear date when the address is set). But now if I add a date, holder.mDate doesn't show the text. Any ideas what's mixed up?

Comment: @user2246120 update your code or I wont be able to see the problem.

Comment: thanks for helping, but that's as designed. I want to either display the date text or address text. Do you mean I can't do that? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Your viewholder holds the view... you only have 1 ciew. Put whatever you fell like in it...

Comment: it worked removing the duplicates but there's still an issue: I added Edit2 to my question